# Loop won't allow float

Tags: python, loops, types

I would like to change the loop so that the user can enter the depth as a decimal.  The weird thing is when I run it with straight integers, the program works fine.  But if I try to input a decimal into depth I receive this error message: 
"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'area' referenced before assignment"

In summation, can I receive a tip on how to change the loop to allow for non-integers? I saw something about xrange, but that confused me. And can someone please explain how I can get a reference error dependent on the user's input?

Thanks

```
width =  float(input("In inches, what is the width: "))
length = float(float(input("In inches, what is the length: ")))
depth = int(float(input("In inches, what is the depth: ")))

for i in range(depth):
    area = 6*(length*width)
    volume = length * width * depth

print ("The area is: ", area, "square inches")
print ("The volume is: ", volume, "cubic inches")
```

Comment: Why do you have a loop there at all?

Comment: How many times should the loop be run if `depth` is 6.2?

Comment: Why are you even using a `for` loop?

Comment: To downvoters: go easy on the newbie.

Comment: Also please describe expected outputs for some input example. `area = 6*(length*width)` does not make much sense in general. Why multiply by 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need depth in decimal, you could directly write

```
depth = float(input("In inches, what is the depth: "))
```

and get rid of the `for` loop

Answer (score 2):

Your `UnboundLocalError` is because `depth` is zero. Since the loop's body isn't being run, area and volume aren't being assigned. It doesn't look like you need a loop there at all, so you can just get rid of the line with the `for` at the start and unindent the next two and you'll be all set.

`xrange` is from versions of Python before 3. If you ever find yourself using one of those, put an `x` in front of `range` and you'll have the semantics you're used to.

Comment: Good point. I use parens in my prints these days and the spaces before them threw me off.

Comment: Actually, they might be using python 2. However, then they shouldn't be using `input`. So nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you have to declare `area` before you use it in the loop.

To solve the more overall problem with your code you should remove the `for` loop completely:

```
width =  float(input("In inches, what is the width: "))
length = float(float(input("In inches, what is the length: ")))
depth = int(float(input("In inches, what is the depth: ")))  # why are you casting this variable as both an int and a float?

area = 6*(length*width)
volume = length * width * depth

print ("The area is: ", area, "square inches")
print ("The volume is: ", volume, "cubic inches")
```

A `for` loop is intended to iterate over an iterable (a list, dictionary etc) and perform an operation on each item in the iterable. Or it can be used with `range` to perform an operation a certain number of times. In you case performing `for i in range(depth)` would be useful if you wanted the user to enter an upper bound for the depth so they could see the area/volume for all the integers up to that number.

For example if they were designing an aquarium and need a minimum volume but could go over a certain volume your function would  be able to help them see what depth's fit the requirements. However what I assume you want is to just calculate the area/volume once so there is no need for a loop at all.

Now as for casting the variable this is read form the inside out. So you are taking `input` which is a `string`, casting it as a `float` (which is what you want), and then casting it as an `int` which will just drop the decimal value off the end. To keep it as a float:

`depth = float(input(blah...))`

is all that is required.